# Building for AVP in Unity - PhaseScriptExecution error in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, visionos, visionos-simulator

Alright, so I am building for AVP in Unity 2022.3.5 following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/LYRJIewPiLU), first trying to achieve the most straightforward windowed result.

I am hitting several issues not addressed online or in the tutorial. Building on device SDK in Player Settings, I get the following build failure in Xcode regardless of whether I target a physical AVP or the simulator:

[image]

Attempting to build on simulator SDK, I get a build failure from Unity due to missing libraries at this path:

[image]

Copying over the relevant files from the iOSSupport folder at the same path allows me to build the Xcode project, but this then gets me back to the same `PhaseScriptExecution` error above.

Why is this occurring? How can I resolve this `PhaseScriptExecution` issue in Xcode?

Confirming I am on Xcode 15.

EDIT - [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/visionos-how-to-build-an-existing-app-for-the-vision-pro-simulator.1472373/) resolves the PhaseScript issue, but leaves me with 4 errors along the lines of:

> Sandbox: il2cpp(67178) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/{user
> name}/Desktop/vos_5/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy_arm64/il2cpp